# Action bar tabs underline color

Tags: android, xml, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar

I am trying to find the method to change the underline color or background of the tabs in action bar through some code but can't find the answer? Please help

Comment: Go through it may helps you http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Android Documentation on customizing the tabs of an Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs):

> "To change the indicator used for the navigation tabs, create an
>   activity theme that overrides the actionBarTabStyle property. This
>   property points to another style resource in which you override the
>   background property that should specify a state-list drawable."

You may also want to look at this [style generation tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100) that I've found helpful.  It will auto generate the Action Bar style based on you GUI selections.  Might be a bit overkill for some basic things.  But, you can also pull out just the styles you need from the generated code.

Comment: how to override the actionBarTabStyle property ?

Comment: @user3091531 see the first link in the post has a example also.